# Why does the Resistance not work with Wallace?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

Okay, so in *Blade Runner 2049* we know Wallace wants to be able to create new Replicants with the ability to reproduce. We also know that the Resistance wants freedom for the Replicants.

Then why is Freysa's movement not helping Wallace to create these new Replicants to develop Replicants' technology even further, and worse, is trying to stop Wallace by asking K to kill Deckard?

As we can see, even the Nexus-9 like K can eventually disobey human orders, so it cannot be because she feared the new Replicants would merely be slaves.